# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression in ms access macro builder

Tags: ms-access, macros

I would like to ask your help regarding MS ACCESS Macro builder. I received this error when searching with two names in one text box but when it is a single name it's working, why is that I received this error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression [First_Name] = 'Steph Jame'.

[[image: Error message]]

Comment: The error is '[First_Name] = Steph Jame' as far as I can see, not as you quoted. You will need quotation marks for a name with a space.

Comment: and how can i do the quotation for a name with a space?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply guys. I already solved this problem. I found an answer from the net.
Here's the solution:
="[First_Name]= '" & Forms![Form Name]![Text box] & "'"

Comment: Watch out for first names with apostrophes, you may need Replace in there.